# Title and Content around image with CSS

Tags: html, css

It’s possible that title and description to start in new row but immediately after photo?

I have explored for this problem, but I cannot find any solution

```
<div  class="ourteam-details col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 lr">
<div class="image">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="../../Articles/10/Images/30-06-2016/197X220903441_ourtteam-bg.png" alt="Our Team articleName 6">
    <div class="featured-overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="details">
    <span class="title">Our Team articleName 6</span>
    </div>
    <span class="content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
```

The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of
letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here'.

And CSS

```
.ourteam-details {padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;overflow: auto;}
.ourteam-details .image {width: auto !Important;max-width: 100%;max-height:100%;padding-right: 20px;}
.ourteam-details .image img {width: 100%;height: auto;}
.ourteam-details .details { width: auto !Important; float: none !important;}
.ourteam-details .title{width: auto !important;font-family: "OpenSans-Bold";font-size: 2.5em;color: #005f9b;}
.ourteam-details .content {width: auto !important;float: none !important;clear: left;font-family: "OpenSans";color: #232323;}
```

*For more description of my problem, you can see one image that I have share.*

[image]

Comment: so many `!important` rules :/

Comment: Add `float: left` to `.title`.

Comment: Title have float:left, but in this case this div mus have WIDTH, and, when i put width, title goes under image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need to use `!important`. Looks fine already, but here you go:

```css
.ourteam-details {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.ourteam-details .image {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.ourteam-details .image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.ourteam-details .details {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
}
.ourteam-details .title {
  width: auto;
  font-family: "OpenSans-Bold";
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #005f9b;
}
.ourteam-details .content {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
  clear: left;
  font-family: "OpenSans";
  color: #232323;
}
.img-responsive {
  float: left;
  width: 200px !important;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ourteam-details col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 lr">
  <div class="image">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvd6S.png" alt="Our Team articleName 6">
    <div class="featured-overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <span class="title">Our Team articleName 6</span>
  </div>
  <span class="content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.
    The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here'.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: No, in your case image is 100% width. I don't need so. See my photo in description. (title and content to start in new line, but after image.

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi Gotcha... Updating the answer, please wait.

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi Check now?

Comment: Yes but there is no change

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi I am seeing [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zYPe6.png) as my output. Don't you get this?

Comment: I need in this form: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2kXTzS9GXEwWmNLc202NFdYdGM

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi You just need to add float left for this. That's all! Lemme update you.

Comment: Thank you. I solve my problem. The fault has been in .title { } This class should not have FLOAT ( .title { float:none: } )

Comment: @ParveenKumar sorry for my mistake that I have done earlier. I accepted your answer

Comment: @RexhepRexhepi No worries. I am **Praveen** not **Parveen**. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  class="row ourteam-details">
    <div class="col-md-6 image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="../../Articles/10/Images/30-06-2016/197X220903441_ourtteam-bg.png" alt="Our Team articleName 6">
        <div class="featured-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 details">
        <h1 class="title">Our Team articleName 6</h1>
        <p class="content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You have used the wrong html tags for heading title and paragraph. Use h1, h2,...& h6 for headers and p for paragraph tags. Also you need to wrap col-* classes with row class .

Comment: Thanks but I need CSS, because HTML is by defalut from CMS :(

Answer (score 0):

```
.title, .content{
display:block;
}
```

This may help you

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but isn't that :(